# Is there any way to have optional methods in an abstract class?

Tags: java

I wanted to have an optional abstract method in my gameobject abstract class but i do not know if that is even possible, i have searched but haven't found a clear answer.

Comment: What is an "optional abstract method"?

Comment: If someone has an instance of a subclass of your abstract class that does not implement the method, and they try to call that method, what should happen?

Comment: I'll edit my question to answer this

Comment: Optional in not providing an implementation? In an abstract class you can provide an empty default implementation and not override it in the concrete class. If you want to prohibit certain implementations from having the method called, then you throw an exception in the default instead.

Comment: I suggest you to put the opional abstract method in another interface, then only the subclasses which need that method will implement that interface

Comment: Since you mentioned the name `gameobject`: most games these days prefer composition over inheritance, often using the [ECS pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system). A great intro is in the book [Game Programming Patterns](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html).

Comment: `i have searched but haven't found a clear answer.` - most likely because it doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the optional method in an interface

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
 abstract void method1();
 abstract void method2();
}
public interface OptionalInterface {
 void optionalMethod();
}

// don't have the optionalMethod
public subClass1 extends SuperClass {
   void method1() {
   
   }
   void method2() {

   }
}

// Implement optionalMethod
public subClass2 extends SuperClass implements OptionalInterface  {
   void method1() {
   
   }
   void method2() {

   }
   void optionalMethod() {

   }
}
```

Comment: How does this make the method optional (what ever that means)?   It's not optional in an interface since you must implement it?  This answer does not make sense.

Comment: You are right. But sometime we must guess the problem in the head of the questionner. The idea behind **optional** in his problem is not about the method itself, but in the fact implementing the method should be optional in subclasses inherit from abstract superClass.

Comment: No.  You really shouldn't guess for an answer.  That is what the comments are for.  To get clarification.  In some cases you may make some minor assumptions.  But the OP provided no hint of what they were looking for.

Comment: We the formatting of comments you cannot always speak in english to understand a problem, sometimes we need an illustrated draft. But with the bad formatting of comment.... Better discuss in an clean code.